# Как получить доступ к элементам, находящимся в Iframe и произвести нажатие?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Как получить, так скажем, доступ к элементам, находящимся в `Iframe` и произвести нажатие!?
Нажатие это понятно

```
$("#button").click();
```

Но не берет это его...
Сразу оговорюсь, `irame` не на том же домене, а от `VK` хочу заменить блок, оставить лишь одну кнопку со своей картинкой.

Comment: так же как и обычно нажимаются кнопки программно, нужно достать адрес в фрейме и произвести нажатие кнопки на этой странице, рекомендую скачать книгу по android и не парить людям мозг

Comment: Вообще ни черта не поняла. Я просила ответ на вопрос, а не книжку, Вам если нужно будет узнать сколько лет Андрею Балканскому, Вы будите Войну и Мир перечитывать?

Comment: я готовый код тебе писать не буду, разве что за деньги, тут или сама или никак

Comment: Просветите, при чем тут Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если домен не тот, то доступ к DOM невозможен. Получите ошибку доступа.

Если в качестве разработки нужно, то можно запустить хром с разрешенным кросдоменным скриптингом, указав параметр --disable-web-security, но для продакшена это естественно бесполезно.

Comment: Спасибо Вам!

Comment: всегда пожалуйста (:

Comment: @DmitryManannikov как я понимаю в таком случае нужно делать браузерный аддон ?

Comment: @Андрей да, аддоны имеют доступ к обоим контекстам

Answer (score 3):

Доступ к iframe с одного домена на дж квери можно сделать так

```
$('iframe').contents().find('body'); - боди вашего фрейма
```

на чистом джс так

```
frames[0].contentWindow.document.body  - боди вашего фрейма
```

Comment: Спасибо, но к сожалению фрэйм не мой